# Hibernate + SQLite db outside jar

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, maven

After few years of `PHP` I decided to learn `Java`, so I'm writing simple desktop app that uses `Hibernate` and `SQLite`.

I'd like to keep database outside of the .jar generated by `mvn package`, so one can perform quick backup of the data just by copying one file. So far, my `hibernate.cfg.xml` looks like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:mydb.db</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="com.ex3v.hibernate.Contact"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

what `connection.url` do I have to specify to make hibernate create db file next to .jar in working directory?

Comment: hi, ex3v. How did you manage to use SQLite with hibernate? I can't find SQLite as supported dialect on this [page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)

Comment: You will have to add `SQLite Dialect` dependency to your project (example 1:  http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/, example 2: http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/7/Annotation-based-Hibernate-Hello-World-example-using-Maven-build-tool-and-SQLite-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answer [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite/Connecting):

Just a summary from above site, 
different formats are :

- `jdbc:sqlite:mydb.db`
- `jdbc:sqlite://dirA/dirB/mydb.db`
- `jdbc:sqlite:/DRIVE:/dirA/dirB/mydb.db`
- `jdbc:sqlite:///COMPUTERNAME/shareA/dirB/mydb.db`

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve the problem. I know that there are few ways to define path, but what EXACTLY should I write to always get RELATIVE path?

Comment: you can use .. operator to travel up the directory hierarchy right? it would help you to put relative path

Comment: Right. Too early for me today... For future generations: i used ` <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:./mydb.db</property>` and it created db in the very same directory as `jar` after first run. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use relative path like this. 
jdbc:sqlite:./DB/mydb.db